# Does every git commit have its own history?

Tags: git

While searching for a bad commit by hand I recognized that the history changes if I checkout a specific commit. Given 2 branches `develop` and `payoff`. I merged `payoff` into `develop` so the history looks like this:

```
A - B - - - E - F - G <- develop
     \     /
      C - D <- payoff
```

`G` is my current `HEAD` of `develop`. `C` and `D` are commits in `payoff`. `E` is the merge commit. If I do `git log` I see following commits: `G - F - E - D - C - B - A`.

Then I checkout `F` and do `git log` again. Now I see this: `F - B - A`. The commits `C` and  `D` are not shown.

Why is that? (btw: `payoff` is still available and not deleted if that matters)

**EDIT**

Here is my `git log` and my `git log --graph --oneline` on HEAD.

[image]

And here it is after checking out commit `Commit B`.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a dummy github/bitbucket repo on which this issue can be reproduced?

Comment: The repo I'm working on is private and I'm not allowed to publish it. But I will try to create another repo for reproducing.

Comment: If you only see E+B+A, then commit `E` is *not* the merge (which is what you drew above), it's commit `F` that is the merge.  Use `git log --graph` (or gitk or some graphical viewer) to confirm this visually.

Comment: You were right and wrong. I changed my drawing and explained which one is the merge commit ( `E` ). And if I checkout any commit after the merge and before HEAD, the history of the merged branch gets lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: now that we have a snapshot of part of the graph, we can tell a lot better what is going on.  I think you are getting tripped up (at least in part) by the fact that `git log` *sorts* the commits it displays, as well as only displaying commits reachable from `HEAD` (or from whatever starting points you list, if any; see earlier answer below this edit).

The graph is fairly complex and I am too lazy to retype most of it so here's some of it converted to plain text (which loses the color but makes it easy to quote).  With any luck I transcribed the abbreviated SHA-1s correctly (they are a pain to retype).

```
* 4d0be7a Commit A
* 2e2be6d Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop' into develop
|\
| *   97504ea Merge branch 'payoff' into develop
| |\
| | * ede23f0 Commit C
| | * 0e1df38 Commit D
[snip]
| * | 9a20c3c Commit x1

[snip - there is another merge in here]

| | * | 0fdd1ff Commit y3
| * | | eed1783 Commit z1
* | | | 43dcf79 Commit B
* | | | bb2bd73 Commit K
```

Note the lines, vertical in this case (instead of horizontal in my original text below), and in color in the screenshot, made of vertical bars `|` connecting commit nodes.

#### Commit sorting

`git log` normally sorts commits in *time* order (according to "committer" time stamp), with the most recent first, so that time stamps get further into the past as you go down the listing (instead of moving further left in a horizontal graph).  When adding `--graph`, `git log` is forced to use a *topological* sort instead.  This sort may produce different results, especially at merge commits where there are two<sup>1</sup> parents.

In a `git log` topological sort, every child commit must be shown before any of its parents are shown.  The topmost merge, `2e2be6d`, is the child of two commits, namely `95704ea` and `43dcf79`

We can see that commit `4d0be7a` is `HEAD` at the time of the `git log --graph` and it is not itself a merge.  Right behind it is `2e2be6d` which *is* a merge, and therefore has two parents.  One parent is `97504ea` (another merge) and the other is `43dcf79` (your "commit B").  Let's look a bit further at *those* commits' parents too: the two parents of `97504ea` are `ede23f0` (Commit C) and `9a20c3c` (Commit x1), and just keep those in the back of our minds.

The time stamp on a merge is (normally<sup>2</sup>) newer than the time stamp on either of its parents.  This means that whether or not you use `--topo-order` to force a topo-sort, or `--graph` which forces it for you, you will see merge `2e2be6d` before both merge `97504ea` and `43dcf79` (Commit B), and you will see merge `97504ea` before `ede23f0` (Commit C) and `9a20c3c` (Commit x1).  The tricky bit comes about immediately after that.

*Without topo order*, in what order will you see commits B, C, and x1?

We cannot tell just from this graph (which is sorted in topo order but does not show the time stamps).  The only way to tell is to look at a different `git log` output, or examine the time stamps on the three commits.  Fortunately we have some of that information in one of your other screenshots, specifically the first one with the full SHA-1 IDs and date fields.  Unfortunately, the date fields shown are the *author* date fields, not the *committer* date fields that git uses for sorting.  Fortunately, these two are probably the same.  Unfortunately we do not see commit x1, but let's just guess that its date is "earlier".

So here we have `4d0be7a` (Commit A) at the top, with the newest date, the afternoon of 15 April.  Below that we have `2e2be6d` (a merge), with a date in the morning of 15 April, and below that we have `43dcf79` (Commit B) with a date stamp after 5 PM of 14 April.  (And all the time zones are +0200, probably Europe somewhere.)  We cannot see merge `97504ea`: it must have a time stamp earlier than that of Commit D.

Hence, when `HEAD` points to Commit A, `git log` will sort these commits so that it shows `A`, then one of the merges-specifically `2e2be6d`, then `B`, then `C`, and so on.  Adding `--topo-order`, or implying it via `--graph`, `git log` changes its sort so that the parents of `2e2be6d` are shown earlier, including the second merge.

If, by doing `git checkout` of some other commit or branch name, we descend into that other part of the graph and run `git log`, we can no longer move back up through the one-way links to reach merge `2e2be6d`, which means we cannot move back down to commit `B`.  This is why B no longer appears in the output.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically a merge is any commit with two *or more* parents, but you only get more if you make an "octopus merge", which we need not worry about here.

<sup>2</sup>I say "normally" because computer clocks can be wrong, and because you can tell git to put a different time stamp (past or future) on any commit.  For instance if you make a commit with a time stamp in year 2038, it will show up at the top of the listing whenever it shows up at all, unless you choose some other sort order.

---

I believe your merge commit is commit `F`, i.e., you could draw this as:

```
A - B -- E --- F   <-- develop
     \       /
       C - D       <-- payoff
```

The answer to the subject-line question:

> Does every git commit have its own history?

is: "yes, sort of, but this may be the wrong way to ask."  That is, don't think of each commit as storing *history* per se, but rather as keeping track of several *metadata* items:

- author (name, email, and date);
- committer (name, email, and date; often the same as author);
- **a list of parent IDs** (bold here because this is the key to this particular question); and
- your commit log message.

A merge commit is any commit with *at least two* parents.  Assuming that `F`—the newest commit on `develop`—is the merge commit, its two parents are `E`, which used to be the tip of `develop` before doing the merge, and `D`, which was and still is the tip of `payoff`.

Commit `E` records its (single) parent, as do `D`, `C`, `B`, and `A`.  Note that while `B` has two *children* (`C` and `D`), commits record *only* their parents.  In order to find siblings or children, git must do some graph reconstruction work—in fact, the same work we did to draw this in the first place.

When you run `git log` (without extra arguments), git starts with your *current commit*.  It keeps track of which commit is current using the special name `HEAD`.  Typically `HEAD` actually contains the name of a branch—that is, `HEAD` refers to `develop` or `payoff`, for instance, and the branch-name in turn refers to the specific commit.  But when you use `git checkout` with a specific commit, like `E` for instance, you get into "detached HEAD" mode, and now `HEAD` contains the raw SHA-1 ID of the specific commit.

Since `git log` starts with the current commit, and commits only contain their parents' IDs, if we start at `E` and work backwards in history, we will only find `E`, then `B`, then `A`, which is what you observed.

You can tell `git log` to start elsewhere: for instance, `git log payoff` starts with whichever commit `payoff` points to (in this case `D`), or `git log develop` starts with whichever commit `develop` points to (in this case, `F`).  Using `--all` tells `git log` to start with every commit found from *every* reference.  We haven't defined "reference" yet here, but the short version is that this means *all* branches, and *all* tags, and even a few special cases that are not branches or tags, such as the special reference that `git stash` uses.

Comment: Nice explanation. My drawing was wrong and bad explained but I fixed it now for better understanding what the issue is. Your answer itself is fine and correct but not exactly the answer to my question.

Comment: @BMS: if you use `git log --graph --oneline` (or `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`), git will draw the graph for you, making it visually obvious which commit is a merge.  Including that in the original question will help.  (Note that you can overwrite the one-line commit message text if those are company secret or whatever; it's the graph drawing that is important here.)

Comment: I've included some screenshots in my original question. The commit messages are changed and the authors are hidden. Does that help?

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that. Just to be sure: If I checkout another commit I can't see the other commits (even if they're commited earlier) because there is no one-way-pointer from this state?
And sorry for screenshotting (instead of copy-pasting).

Comment: More accurately, because all the pointers are one-way, and `git log` normally only follows them in the "easy" direction.  (Hence my comment on CodeWizard's answer that the arrows in his last diagram point the wrong way.)  To go backwards—which `git rev-list` can do, sort of; see `--children`—git must first construct the entire graph, then reverse (or make double-headed) each arc-arrow.  (There are algorithms for doing this in small amounts of memory, but git mostly just throws memory at the problem.)

Answer (score 2):

> bad commit by hand I ..

git has a build in mechanism for that.

bisect:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html

Here is a demo now to use it to find the desired commit:
https://github.com/nirgeier/Tutorials-bisect

---

**To answer your question.**

Each commit does have its own reference to the prior commit in the commit chain.
A commit is also known as ***`snapshot`***.

[image]

---

> Does every git commit have its own history?

You can see in the image below how does git store the information about all the commits.

Each commit (snapshot) has **all** the content which was committed.
This is the `snapshot`.

[image]

---

In your case you have branches which result in several commits. Each branch points to its own commit (snapshot) which can looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a nice graphical git divagation, which unfortunately doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: He asked how come he see the commits in different branches and why are they orders in the way he described.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the arrows in the last diagram (with round commit nodes) point "the wrong way", forwards in time instead of backwards: from parents to children.  Git points the arrows the other way because it must: commits, once made, cannot be changed, but new children can be added at any time.  The arrows must therefore point only to parents (it is impossible to add new parents).

Comment: Which letter/number do refer to?. as i see it there was a merge between master and topic and then the work continued on both of them.